# How to do a Remote procedure call over POSTMAN?

Tags: postman, rpc, json-rpc

Is it possible to make a remote procedure call in POSTMAN?

If it's possible, can some one show me an example in POSTMAN how to make a RPC call to this [get_session_key](https://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_get_session_key) method.

Comment: there is a ticket to add native support of json rpc to postman https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7286

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example I saw on [this website](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=327119)

Postman URL: https://username:password@ipaddress:portnumber/jsonrpc

Content-type:application/json

Method: POST

Body: {"jsonrpc”: "2.0”, "method”: "Input.Up”, "id": 1}

[image: postman request screenshot]